# DynamoDB. How to scan list with contains

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

```
ValueMap attributes = new ValueMap()
.withBoolean( ":p_deleted", true )
.withString( ":p_prefix", prefix );
ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec()
.withFilterExpression( UAwsBasic.DATABASE_JSON_DEFINITION_NAME + ".deleted = :p_deleted and " + dynamoDbCommon.RANGE_KEY_NAME + " contains :p_prefix" ).withValueMap( attributes );

ItemCollection< ScanOutcome > items1 = dynamoDbCommon.scanList(getTableName(), scanSpec );
```

How to get items list?

I need get not deleted items with prefix.

I have an error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "contains", near: "path contains :p_prefix"
```

I've tried write the simmilar scan-request:

```
ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec().withScanFilters( new ScanFilter[] { typeFilter, deletedFilter } ).withConditionalOperator( ConditionalOperator.AND );
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: is it normal that you have a colon on the boolean (:p_deleted) but not on the string (:p_prefix) ?

Comment: No. it isn't normal, thanks! But it doesn't wotk with ':'

Comment: from your error it seems that you cant test for "contains" in the key in the filterexpression. I'm no expert on that, but I think you can only test key for equality, not subproperties?

Comment: Scan - can read nested queries. (subproperties.)  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 ValueMap values = new ValueMap().withString( ":p_status", "READY" ).withString( ":p_prefix", prefix );

NameMap names = new NameMap().with( "#status_name", "status" ).with( "#path_name", CDynamoDbCommon.RANGE_KEY_NAME );


scanSpec = new ScanSpec()
    .withFilterExpression( UAwsBasic.DATABASE_JSON_DEFINITION_NAME + ".#status_name = :p_status AND contains( #path_name , :p_prefix)" )
    .withNameMap( names ).withValueMap( values )
    .withMaxResultSize( 10 ).withExclusiveStartKey( CDynamoDbCommon.PRIMARY_KEY_NAME, primaryLast, CDynamoDbCommon.RANGE_KEY_NAME, hashLast );
```